# Is it possible to load the contents of a single class file into an Object, and cast it into a spicific type?

Tags: java, file, module, classpath

I'm trying to create a piece of software for remote PC moderation which is comprised of two parts.

Client: run on people's PCs which listens to the server over a socket with a BufferedReader for commands

Server: allows for multiple clients to connect, and can send individual commands to each one.

The only problem is that some clients may require different command types. For example I might want to be able to request a picture from my desktop's webcam, and be able to see what's going on in my room at any time. But I don't want to install this feature on all clients. Because that would be creepy.

I was wondering if I could create an abstract class, say Module, which has an abstract method with the parameters of the communication socket. And create individual class files extending Module to be downloaded to the client and added to the clients class path.

Is it possible to load the contents of a single class file into an Object, and cast it into a specific type?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're looking for is information about how to write your own Classloader, which would load a class from memory after it has been transferred across a network connection. Yes, it's possible, and now that you know the key word you should be able to find a fair amount of documentation for that on the web.

Whether it's the right way to architect your application is a separate question. It sounds to me like you aren't actually giving people more control, just the illusion of more control (unless they unplug their network connection after installing/loading your framework), so I'm not convinced it's the right answer.

Comment: I looked around, and I found this:

Comment: File file = new File("c:\\myclasses\\");

try {
    // Convert File to a URL
    URL url = file.toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    // Create a new class loader with the directory
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    // Load in the class; MyClass.class should be located in
    // the directory file:/c:/myclasses/com/mycompany
    Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}

Comment: But it returns a Class object, is it possible to cast this into a normal Object? or into an instance of an interface?

Comment: No, you don't cast it -- you use it through Java reflection to create an instance of the class (which then implements the same interfaces it would if you created it other way.)